# Error: Could not symlink include/php /usr/local/include is not writable

Tags: php, homebrew

When i run brew link php

```
Linking /usr/local/Cellar/php/7.2.5... 
Error: Could not symlink include/php
/usr/local/include is not writable.
```

And i try

```
MacBook-Pro:local Fatm$ sudo chown -R $(whoami) /usr/local
chown: /usr/local: Operation not permitted
```

I can't find include

```
MacBook-Pro:local Fatm$ ls -a           
.github     CODEOFCONDUCT.md        Homebrew     bin    
remotedesktop     .gitignore    Caskroom    LICENSE.txt         
etc             sbin      .com.apple.installer.keep    .travis.yml           
Cellar              Library             lib             share
.git                .yardopts           Frameworks          README.md               
opt               var

MacBook-Pro:local Fatm$ sudo chown -R $(whoami) /usr/local/include
Password:
chown: /usr/local/include: No such file or directory
```

How can i solve the problem

Comment: it is probably /usr/local that is not writable by your user:group .

Answer (score 9):

homebrew /usr/local is not writable in high sierra (if **include** folder doesn't exist). Go ahead and create it and then change the permission of it to yourself.

```
cd /usr/local
sudo mkdir include
sudo chown -R $(whoami) $(brew --prefix)/include
```

After that try your brew command

Comment: I also had to `sudo mkdir lib` and `sudo chown -R $(whoami) $(brew --prefix)/lib`